# I am working on a simple tutorial app for English learning and i am having a trouble with setting the numbering position

Tags: java, android, listview

**MainActivity.java**:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Resources res= getResources();
        mainTopic=res.getStringArray(R.array.MainTopic);
        mainDescription=res.getStringArray(R.array.DescriptionContent);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,mainTopic,image1,mainDescription);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

My **activity_main.xml** file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyAdapter.java**:

```
    package androidthirst.company.abhi.totalenglish;



    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] MainTopic,String[] img,String[] description) {
        super(context,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView,MainTopic);
        this.context=context;
        this.MainTopic=MainTopic;
        this.img=img;
        this.description=description;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int  position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View row=  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
       TextView imageView= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      TextView textView1= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
       TextView textView2= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        for (int i =1;i<=position;i++) {
            imageView.setText(""+i);

        }
    
         textView1.setText(MainTopic[position]);
        textView2.setText(description[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

I just want to put one at 1 row.

[image: Here you can see the image]

Comment: change your for(int i = 1...){} for imageView.setText("" + (position + 1));

Comment: Not working now It's starting from 11

Comment: Why are you even using the for loop in there? You are setting the text of the text view until it reaches position. So the final text of the view is always the current position of the item to display. remove the for loop and set the text with 'imageView.setText(""+position)' and you're done. The actual error is, that you start the loop with 1 instead of 0. And if you don't want it to start with 0, use @Luis Miguel Sierra's solution.

Comment: @GPuschka Thats it. Guess he must use (position + 1) to show the index as 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is ultimately setting value of position in imageView. But position starts from 0, so you have to add 1 in each.
Replace you this loop

```
for (int i =1;i<=position;i++) {
    imageView.setText(""+i);

}
```

with

```
imageView.setText(""+(position+1));
```

Comment: Thanks dude , i did it finally 
I changed my for loop to for(int i=1;i<=position+1;i++) and it's work properly

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this loop:

```
for (int i =1;i<=position;i++) {
  imageView.setText(""+i);
}
```

by this:

```
imageView.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
```

NOTE: you don't need the loop because the getView function is inflating row by row with it's position. It's not inflating all rows at the same time.